# Wordpress mobile version is not responsive anymore after installing varnish

Tags: cache, mobile, varnish

```
# Default backend definition. Set this to point to your content server.
backend default {
    .host = "127.0.0.1";
    .port = "8080";
}

sub vcl_recv {
  # Set the X-Forwarded-For header so the backend can see the original
  # IP address. If one is already set by an upstream proxy, we'll just re-use that.

  #return(pass);

  if (req.method == "PURGE") {
     return (purge);
  }

  if (req.method == "XCGFULLBAN") {
     ban("req.http.host ~ .*");
     return (synth(200, "Full cache cleared"));
  }

  if (req.http.X-Requested-With == "XMLHttpRequest") {
     return(pass);
  }

  if (req.http.Authorization || req.method == "POST") {
     return (pass);
  }

  if (req.method != "GET" && req.method != "HEAD") {
     return (pass);
  }

  if (req.url ~ "(wp-admin|post\.php|edit\.php|wp-login|wp-json)") {
     return(pass);
  }

  if (req.url ~ "/wp-cron.php" || req.url ~ "preview=true") {
     return (pass);
  }
  if (req.url ~ "/xmlrpc.php" || req.url ~ "preview=true") {
     return (pass);
  }

  if ((req.http.host ~ "sitename.com" && req.url ~ "^some_specific_filename\.(css|js)")) {
     return (pass);
  }

# Unset Cookies except for WordPress admin and WooCommerce pages
if (!(req.url ~ "(cart|my-account/*|wc-api*|checkout|addons|logout|lost-password|ask-question|product/*)")) {
unset req.http.cookie;
}
# Pass through the WooCommerce dynamic pages
if (req.url ~ "^/(cart|my-account/*|checkout|wc-api/*|addons|logout|lost-password|ask-question|product/*)") {
return (pass);
}
# Pass through the WooCommerce add to cart
if (req.url ~ "\?add-to-cart=" ) {
return (pass);
}
# Pass through the WooCommerce API
if (req.url ~ "\?wc-api=" ) {
return (pass);
}

  set req.http.Cookie = regsuball(req.http.Cookie, "(^|;\s*)(_[_a-z]+|has_js)=[^;]*", "");

  # Remove the wp-settings-1 cookie
  set req.http.Cookie = regsuball(req.http.Cookie, "wp-settings-1=[^;]+(; )?", "");

  # Remove the wp-settings-time-1 cookie
  set req.http.Cookie = regsuball(req.http.Cookie, "wp-settings-time-1=[^;]+(; )?", "");

  # Remove the wp test cookie
  set req.http.Cookie = regsuball(req.http.Cookie, "wordpress_test_cookie=[^;]+(; )?", "");

  # Remove the PHPSESSID in members area cookie
  set req.http.Cookie = regsuball(req.http.Cookie, "PHPSESSID=[^;]+(; )?", "");

  unset req.http.Cookie;
}

sub vcl_purge {
    set req.method = "GET";
    set req.http.X-Purger = "Purged";

    #return (synth(200, "Purged"));
    return (restart);
}

sub vcl_backend_response {
    # Happens after we have read the response headers from the backend.
    #
    # Here you clean the response headers, removing silly Set-Cookie headers
    # and other mistakes your backend does.

    set beresp.grace = 12h;
    set beresp.ttl = 12h;
}

sub vcl_deliver {
    # Happens when we have all the pieces we need, and are about to send the
    # response to the client.
    #
    # You can do accounting or modifying the final object here.
}
```

This is my default.vcl configuration. My problem is my site is no longer responsive on mobile it keeps showing the desktop version.

Any ideas  ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It' entirely possible that WordPress detects the device based on the `User-Agent` requests header and displays the right version of the website accordingly.

If you don't instruct Varnish to create a cache variation depending on the device, only one version will be cached per page.

## Device detection

Varnish is able to perform device detection by performing `User-Agent` introspection. You could include the following VCL snippet to accelerate the process: https://github.com/varnishcache/varnish-cache/blob/master/etc/devicedetect.vcl.

In order to trigger the device detection subroutine, the `devicedetect.vcl` file needs to be included and executed via `call devicedetect` as illustrated below:

```
include "devicedetect.vcl";
sub vcl_recv {
    call devicedetect;
}
```

The VCL code will generate a custom `X-UA-Device` request header that contains the device type. This will be either:

- pc
- bot
- mobile-bot
- mobile-iphone
- mobile-firefoxos
- mobile-smartphone
- mobile-generic
- mobile-smartphone
- mobile-android
- tablet-ipad
- tablet-android
- tablet-rim
- tablet-hp
- tablet-microsoft
- tablet-kindle

## Cache variation

Based on the `X-UA-Device` header, you can create a cache variation by modifying the `sub vcl_hash` logic:

```
sub vcl_hash {
  if(req.http.X-UA-Device ~ "(mobile|tablet)") {
    hash_data("mobile");
  }
}
```

This VCL snippet makes sure there is a 2nd version of the cached object for mobile devices and tablets.

Comment: hi thanks for the answer but do i need to include in custom.vcl this devicedetect.vcl and if yes like how include devicedetect.vcl at the end of custom.vcl or ?

Comment: i tried it with with https://github.com/varnishcache/varnish-cache/blob/master/etc/devicedetect.vcl with include "/etc/varnish/devicedetect.vcl"; didn't work

Comment: "Didn't work" is unfortunately a very vague term. All the ingredients are there to make it work. There's probably an issue somewhere that can be discovered by performing some debugging.

Comment: I would advise you to log the `X-UA-Device` header by adding `std.log(req.http.X-UA-Device)` and looking at Varnishlog output.

You can use Varnishlog to debug the hash that was composed. By default hash composition is not visible, but by adding `hash` to the `vsl_mask` runtime parameter, you'll be able to look into it. See https://varnishcache.org/docs/6.0/reference/varnishd.html#vsl-mask

Based on the debugging information, I can help you figure out what's actually wrong.

Comment: hmm tried that also

Comment: Please also perform `call devicedetect` to execute the device detection subroutine.